# Como formatar InputNumber do antd para aceitar "," para decimal e "." para centesimal

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, estou usando o InputNumber do antd. Nesse exemplo abaixo o antd está usando regex então ele formata o numero, porem ele aceita apenas o "." logo eu não poderia digitar simplesmente "10,5" mas sim "10.5"

```
 <InputNumber
  formatter={value => `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
  parser={value => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')}
/>
```

Bom, o que eu preciso fazer é formatar com "," para quando for decimal (exemplo: 15,8) e formatar com "." para quando for um numero milesimal (exemplo: 1.000) ou seja, precisa estar no formato BRL.

Porem o antd não possui um formatador para BRL por padrão, ele tem uma propriedade que chama *decimalSeparator* mas quando tento usa-lo neste exemplo o comportamento dos números ficam incorretos (exemplo: se eu digitar 10.000 o resultado seria 1,0,000). A minha dificuldade com o antd é juntar esse dois pontos (formatar para quando for decimal e para quando for centesimal).

Como não entendo muito sobre regex, gostaria de saber se é possível resolver o meu problema usando apenas regex, ou se eu teria que de alguma forma criar uma função e uma logica para realizar essa formatação por padrão.

Não sou muito bom com logica de programação, estou trabalhando nisso todos os dias para melhora-la, gostaria que vcs me desse um caminho para seguir. Obrigado desde já !

Comment: Não podes usar o teu `locale`? https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/locale/pt_BR.tsx

Comment: humm, não entendi muito bem, olhei o codigo mas ele não parece estar relacionado ao meu problema, poderia me explicar melhor ?

Comment: O Antd permite configurar o `locale`, para formatar numeros e legendas em linguas diferentes. https://ant.design/components/config-provider/#Does-the-locale-problem-still-exist-in-DatePicker-even-if-ConfigProvider-locale-is-used?

Comment: bom, acho que isso não resolve o meu problema, mas eu vou tentar, Obrigado !

Comment: Não pode ser desta forma? 
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

Comment: Vê se este link também ajuda... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556221/how-do-you-format-a-number-to-currency-when-using-react-native-expo

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !